# Combining two equations for two conditions

Tags: notation

I am trying to construct a peak model equation where:

When x is equal to or less than the mean y is calculated using the Gaussian distribution equation, and when x is more than the mean the Lorentzian/Cauchy model is used instead.

I wanted to know if there was a specific mathematical way of writing this, or the best way to represent this (in equation form) in scientific text. I am not a mathematician, so apologies if this is a very simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [piecewise defined function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise). If $M$ is the mean, you can write it
$$y = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\text{<formula 1>} &\text{if }x\leq M,\\
\text{<formula 2>} &\text{if }x\gt M.
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: excellent, thank you very much